# Typescript Conditional Type not working when used in a function argument

Tags: typescript

I want a key of an interface to be added conditionally, for that use-case I tried doing

`key: a extends b ? keyValue : never`

but not only does that break when `a` is generic, it also requires me to pass never as the value to the key ?

The questions are, how do I make that genric work and how to "filter" out never types so that I don't have to pass them explicitly.

[Typescript Playground with the below example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDCEC2kB2wcwA8AKnKDPgCYDO6Wu+MAMgJbUwB8cAvHAN4BYAFABIFpQBccYgG5hIgNbjqUgOLAYABSgQw1El3JVafOAGMAFiwA2lKPikAlYGeiVC7KCxwBzADRwAIY4iFwAvnAA-HCe3j4A2gC6cFJ4AG7AUHJCYdnCwgD0BegWwT6oAOpQgWAoUAgQcABCAK4wMBA4QTiUcIgQLXAA7jbWMcCoMKXwSpTEyKiWZcC0AEYaQxNdsb5J3b3pmXDWLAqoLPBsMS21ENTAvR2Fxa3wgbTBQVA+LZiMDXB7BhsJ1-hcgtYhoFELQpt4FLDpggLKhZrRdDAWJ04FdDlAAsFeuDAtZqI13gi4H8AT4WBkcW84Hi4BisV1IpFhEgUHAqjU6tpdLReOotDo9IQAER82qZSUcLkLOCzeY83gygXi2hGHomSw2OwOODOVxQdw7fzdUJwCLRC17VLADJZOCu-JCVw4diA4DAhgEHhwEhkEAUXV0EF4AisdgcAAUgW+AAYnC43B4YF5fAE-aCCAYOABKHhcPi5d1A+h5mBxwSiVZtDo4ACMUj44ikkteTclNr88iG1VlUFb-A7cGlQ7qkoCaKk8UlksSYX7OULeSEwjSid5U6OvFr8n1tnsOFXYTbR6sJ6NuajRAA5BrMg+uAAfCP+x-dzqv4RhYtuFLeR7BgFooC6SV7ECMwYAAOlcSNGElf8N23eofy6A86xEChQ3PS9RDwmApAtf9AOA0RQPArpmwAJgAZlQ910M-athX4eRn3xeRMPPDdhFASBYAQJU70YGN4G4eQPyfPcoAfGS4AfTDFM3IQhOgeBuVQUVBQlUgdRoNj70krheE0RNAj+CgoH0HSIAAMxMxhqHiYhEg4eIk0SAShCAA)

```
export type Component<T extends ComponentList> = {
    id: T;
    kids: GetProps<T> extends { children: Record<string, any> } ? string[] : never;
};


// Change Wrapper to Button and you will see that kidType changes between string[] and never like it is supposed to
// But as an argument to reComponent it always thinks that the kids option is never, and it also asks me to give it a never option ??
type WrapperProps = GetProps<"Wrapper">
type kidType = WrapperProps extends {children: Record<string, any> } ? string[] : never;   

const reComponent = <T extends ComponentList>(arg0: Record<string, Component<T>>) => {};

reComponent({
    button1: {id: "Button" },
    wrapper1: {id: "Wrapper", kids: [""]},
});


var Wrapper = ({
    children,
}: {
    children: Component<'Wrapper'> | Component<'Button'>
}) => {
    return "react.component"
};

var Button = ({
    text,
}: {
    text: string
}) => {
    return 123
};

var Components = {
    Wrapper,
    Button,
};


export type ComponentList =
    | 'Wrapper'
    | 'Button'

export type GetProps<T extends ComponentList> = Parameters<typeof Components[T]>[0];
```

Comment: When I follow the link to the playground, I get only one line of code. Could you please fix this?

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl sorry seems to work now

Comment: I still have the same problem.

Comment: I don't, just copy paste what is in the code box then

Comment: [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WzARQm)

Comment: Thanks. Your example is a bit too complex and hard to grasp. Maybe it is because you try to include two problems in one example. I have tried to solve the second problem, about eliminating a key conditionally. Please create a new question with a simple example to demonstrate the first problem, about the generic type.

Answer (score 1):

Type `never` cannot be used to remove a key from an interface. For example:

```
type testNever = {
    x : string;
    y : never;
}

var tn: testNever = { x: 'ab' }   // error: property 'y' is missing
```

Type `never` is meant to be used as the type of a function to indicate that it will never return. See [TypeScript Handbook, section 'More on functions'](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#never)

You can use the question mark to make a key optional and use keyword `Required` to make a version of the type in which the key is required. Here is an example:

```
type TypeWithOptionalY = {
    x : string;
    y? : string;
}

type TypeWithRequiredY = Required<TypeWithOptionalY>

type WithOrWithoutY = 'requiredY' | 'optionalY'

type ConditionalY<T extends WithOrWithoutY> =
    T extends 'requiredY'
        ? TypeWithRequiredY
        : TypeWithOptionalY

var objWithoutY : ConditionalY<'optionalY'> = { x: 'abc' }   
var objWithY : ConditionalY<'requiredY'> = { x: 'abc', y: 'def' }
```

Comment: That doesn't work if 'optionalY' needs to be inferred by typescript, e.g. when you are passing `{type: "optionalY"}` as an object into a function as an argument. If you try to apply this to the example I gave it unfortunately looses type information and just unions everything together :(